# Attendance Date in PhD

Tags: phd, graduate-school, united-states, application

I am applying for PhD for Fall 2024 in the US, I am still pursuing my masters degree. In the applications they ask for the attendance date for every institution, I am expecting to graduate in Spring 2024, so do I put the attendance date between 08-2021 to 05-2024 or 08-2021 to 12-2023?
And if the former, how does it differ from the expected graduation date? ( which they ask for later).

Comment: You will graduate in the spring, so you will attend through the spring semester.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably write "08-2021 to present" for attendance date, and 05-2024 for expected graduation.

If you are forced to give a date rather than the word present such as due to some online application system, I think it's fine to also put your expected attendance dates, that is, through 05-2024 even if it's a bit redundant with the graduation date. There are some cases where they could differ such as if degrees are only conferred in spring but you complete your coursework in fall (or only conferred in spring or fall but you complete coursework in a summer term and have to wait until the end of fall semester to actually get your degree).

No one is going to penalize you for whatever you write there as long as it's reasonable, though. No one is going to say "aha! Cheater! You claim to have attended something in the future how could that even be possible!"; similarly if you say you're attending now and graduating in spring they'll assume you will actually attend in spring too and have only entered your attendance to date.

Comment: I mean, a large fraction of PhD applications due soon are by current students who won't graduate until next spring. This is not a trick question meant to trip anyone up.